# How can I put the value of this three variables out of the function with the value inside the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Where is the code, I want to take the WarriorTurnOrder, PriestTurnOrder and enemy_turnOrder, with the value inside the function.

```
def initiative_phase(): #Function for setting the turn order
    WarriorTurnOrder = 0
    PriestTurnOrder = 0
    enemy_turnOrder = 0
    
    WarriorTurnOrder = WarriorTurnOrder + random.randint(0,20) + warrior[4] #Random Value for the Warrior's turn number
    PriestTurnOrder = PriestTurnOrder + random.randint(0,20) + priest[4] #Random Value for the Priest's turn number
    enemy_turnOrder = enemy_turnOrder + random.randint(0,20) + vampire[4] #Random Value for the Vampire's turn number
    
    print("\nThe warrior got " + str(WarriorTurnOrder)) 
    print("The vampire got " + str(enemy_turnOrder))
    print("The priest got " + str(PriestTurnOrder))
```

I was trying to do a system of turn order but it keeps giving me an error or a 0 on each value.

```
def first_turn():
    if (WarriorTurnOrder > enemy_turnOrder) and (WarriorTurnOrder > PriestTurnOrder): #Warrior first
        warrior_turn()
    elif (PriestTurnOrder > enemy_turnOrder) and (PriestTurnOrder > WarriorTurnOrder): #Priest first
        priest_turn()
    elif (enemy_turnOrder > WarriorTurnOrder) and (enemy_turnOrder > PriestTurnOrder): #Enemy goes first
        enemy_turn()
    elif (WarriorTurnOrder == enemy_turnOrder) or (WarriorTurnOrder == PriestTurnOrder): #In case of draw return to turn order
        initiative_phase()
    elif (PriestTurnOrder == enemy_turnOrder) or (PriestTurnOrder == WarriorTurnOrder): #In case of draw return to turn order
        initiative_phase()
    elif (enemy_turnOrder == WarriorTurnOrder) or (enemy_turnOrder == PriestTurnOrder): #In case of draw return to turn
        initiative_phase()
        
def second_turn():
    if (WarriorTurnOrder > enemy_turnOrder) and (WarriorTurnOrder < PriestTurnOrder): #Warrior second
        warrior_turn()
    elif (PriestTurnOrder > enemy_turnOrder) and (PriestTurnOrder < WarriorTurnOrder): #Priest second
        priest_turn()
    elif (enemy_turnOrder > WarriorTurnOrder) and (enemy_turnOrder < PriestTurnOrder): #Enemy second
        enemy_turn()

def third_turn():
    if (WarriorTurnOrder < enemy_turnOrder) and (WarriorTurnOrder < PriestTurnOrder): #Warrior third
        warrior_turn()
    elif (PriestTurnOrder < enemy_turnOrder) and (PriestTurnOrder < WarriorTurnOrder): #Priest second
        priest_turn()
    else: #Enemy third
        enemy_turn()
```

Comment: `WarriorTurnOrder ` is a local variable that only exists inside the `initiative_phase()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

METHOD 1:
All these variables that you declare in a function are local variables.
Use `global variable` in your functions. For example: `global WarriorTurnOrder`. Do this for all 3 variables and it should work as you want.

```
def initiative_phase(): #Function for setting the turn order
    global WarriorTurnOrder
    global PriestTurnOrder
    global enemy_turnOrder

    WarriorTurnOrder = 0
    PriestTurnOrder = 0
    enemy_turnOrder = 0
    
    WarriorTurnOrder = WarriorTurnOrder + random.randint(0,20) + warrior[4] #Random Value for the Warrior's turn number
    PriestTurnOrder = PriestTurnOrder + random.randint(0,20) + priest[4] #Random Value for the Priest's turn number
    enemy_turnOrder = enemy_turnOrder + random.randint(0,20) + vampire[4] #Random Value for the Vampire's turn number
    
    print("\nThe warrior got " + str(WarriorTurnOrder)) 
    print("The vampire got " + str(enemy_turnOrder))
    print("The priest got " + str(PriestTurnOrder))
```

METHOD 2 (better practice): Use your variables as function arguments and add `return` statement with a tuple or a list of all 3 variables (this will return a tuple or a list with their values) at the end of your function. You can pass these values later in other functions.

```
def initiative_phase(): #Function for setting the turn order
    WarriorTurnOrder = 0
    PriestTurnOrder = 0
    enemy_turnOrder = 0

    WarriorTurnOrder = WarriorTurnOrder + random.randint(0,20) + warrior[4] #Random Value for the Warrior's turn number
    PriestTurnOrder = PriestTurnOrder + random.randint(0,20) + priest[4] #Random Value for the Priest's turn number
    enemy_turnOrder = enemy_turnOrder + random.randint(0,20) + vampire[4] #Random Value for the Vampire's turn number

    print("\nThe warrior got " + str(WarriorTurnOrder)) 
    print("The vampire got " + str(enemy_turnOrder))
    print("The priest got " + str(PriestTurnOrder))

    #the order of these variables is the order you need to unpack them
    return (WarriorTurnOrder, PriestTurnOrder, enemy_turnOrder)
```

Unpacking these values:

```
WarriorTurnOrder, PriestTurnOrder, enemy_turnOrder = initiative_phase()
```

Other functions should be define like this:

```
def function(WarriorTurnOrder, PriestTurnOrder, enemy_turnOrder):
    #put your code here
```

Comment: But that will always put the value inside, more and more again, I want it to be reset when the function starts again.

Comment: I have edited the post so you can understand what I meant. With putting `global` at the start of a function, all changes that you make inside that function will be visible everywhere in your code. With setting each variable to 0 at the start, you are basiclly reseting variable values.

Comment: Your the best man, thank you!

Comment: Just accept my answer so people with your problem can see the solution

Comment: I need to wait to accept the answer, but I will!

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: @quamrana He can then use all these 3 variables as function parameters and then returning a tuple/list of their values that he then needs to unpack before calling another function. But from what I can see he is a beginner so global variables are more then enough for him to start with.

Comment: Hmm, but I want to teach that while globals can solve a problem, they are terrible as the building blocks of most programs.

Comment: @quamrana I have edited my answer so everyone can see both methods.

Comment: Yes. Excellent work.